# NSTableView delegate inside Nib

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have a `NSWindowController` as part of the work flow with `NSDocument`.  The `NSWindowController` has an associated xib with a couple of `NSTableViews`.  The datasource for these tableviews is a model defined by the `NSDocument`.  I seem to be missing some information on setting up the outlets.  If I setup all the outlets within IB, the datasource(s) are created at the time the nib is instantiated with their default init methods, which don't know about the model.  By the time `awakeFromNib` is called, the datasource has already been queried by the tableview (`numberOfRowsInTableView`).  My work-around is to not hook up the outlets for datasource.  I get the model information in setDocument and set the delegates in `windowDidLoad`.  This seems to work.  How do I pass around a data model when setting the tableview datasource with IB?  Since the outlets are not created when init is called (within the tableview datasource), how would I call out to get the model?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not setting the document as datasource?

Comment: @Volker - I have multiple tables.  Ultimately, the document is the datasource.  I would like to not test for which table called the datasource, so I created separate datasource objects for each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an explicit note in the [NSTabelView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Important: It’s possible that your data source methods for populating
>   the table view may be called before awakeFromNib is called if the data
>   source is specified in Interface Builder. You should defend against
>   this by having the data source’s numberOfRowsInTableView: method
>   return 0 for the number of rows when the data source has not yet been
>   configured. In awakeFromNib, when the data source is initialized you
>   should always call reloadData on the table view.

Comment: As pointed out in other SO posts, awakeFromNib can be called more than  once when there is a chain of objects getting instantiated from the nib.  I guess my question was really: "Is there a way to have IB not call init on some objects, but let some other earlier process instantiate them with specialized init methods and have IB connect those objects?"

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to modify the instantiation process. But instead of fighting the system I'd do the usual connections and all that and act in awakeFromNib as I need it.